# i10n angularjs assign translate variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translation

Okay so i have the following small translation file:

```
    {
    "components" : {
    "1" : "Video",
    "2" : "Lyd",
    "3" : "Dokument",
    "4" : "Tekst"
}

}
```

And then i have the following li item:

```
<li ng-repeat="type in componentTypes" ng-hide="module.module_type_id == 2 || module.module_type_id == 10"><a href="" ng-click="addComponent(type)" translate="components.{{1}}">{{type.name}}</a></li>
```

What you need to notice is :

```
<a href="" ng-click="addComponent(type)" translate="components.{{1}}">{{type.name}}</a>
```

Or more precisely:

```
translate="components.{{1}}"
```

With this it does not translate the `<a></a>` tag.

However if i do

```
translate="components.1"
```

it translates correctly however this method doesnt work for me

so my question is how can dynamicly change the value of a the translate attribute?

Comment: how about {{components.1}} ?

Comment: What exactly is the dependency ? Is `1` a value which is a property in `type` ? What do you need to be inside the `translate` attribute ?

Comment: Just to be sure - are we talking about *angular-translate* and its `translate` directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `components.{{1}}` is not working is because the double curlies in Angular is just meant to evaluate an expression. 1 is just a number, so you'll get `components.1` everytime.

If I understand what you need correctly, you need to have a corresponding component based on type. So if `type.id === 1` then your type is `Video`.

In order to achieve that in Angular dynamically, you should just have:

```
translate="{{components[type.id]}}"
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12036/)

Comment: are you Polish by any chance, I'm asking because you fiddle have some polish words inside :) where did you get it from?

Comment: @Urahara Hehe no, I took an existing basic template and modified it :) If you're talking about the contents of the components object, then it came from the OP's code.

Comment: Alright I'm still upping your answer, at the first glimpse I proposed {{components.1}} but I forgot to evaluate the " 1 " . Thanks for useful hint!

Comment: @Urahara Fair enough!

Comment: Hey Omri. The fiddle you have expect that there is a variable called components however the script i have is setting alot of variables using strings. This means that components[type.id] is undefined since components is not an array

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Can you update the fiddle above with the correct structure ? I was just guessing since I don't really know how it's defined.

Comment: @OmriAharon Sure give me a sec

Comment: @OmriAharon Erm not im not quite able to can we take this in chat instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73564/discussion-between-omri-aharon-and-marc-rasmussen).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to dynamize the translation json if added a new type to your **componentTypes** array.

There is a solution for that need, you can implement a new custom translation loader factory and use it with specified way here https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading. After that you have to add this new item to the translation *json*, your array and then refresh the translation.

View:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="type.name" /> <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="addComponent(type)">Add Component</a>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="type in componentTypes" ng-hide="module.module_type_id == 2 || module.module_type_id == 10">{{ 'components.' + type.name | translate }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Implementation of your application:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

var components_en = {
    "components": {
        "1": "Video",
            "2": "Lyd",
            "3": "Dokument",
            "4": "Tekst"
    }
};

myApp.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader', {});
    $translateProvider.translations('en', components_en);
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
    $scope.module = {
        module_type_id: 1
    };

    $scope.addComponent = function (type) {
        // Add the componentTypes array you took from database
        $scope.componentTypes.push({
            name: $scope.componentTypes.length + 1
        });

        // Add the translation object
        components_en["components"][$scope.componentTypes.length] = type.name;
        console.log(components_en);
        $translate.refresh();
    };

    $scope.componentTypes = [{
        name: 1
    }, {
        name: 2
    }, {
        name: 3
    }, {
        name: 4
    }];
});

myApp.factory('customLoader', function ($http, $q) {
    return function (options) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve(components_en);

        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

I prepared a demonstration for that like usage, please below jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nerezo/1z071wzg/6/

**Note:** This like translation modifications will not be persistent and new translations will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
translate="{{'components.' + type.id}}" //if there is id in type
```

or

```
translate="{{'components.' + ($index + 1)}}"
```

Comment: Then could you tell me if this specific one is works: translate="{{'components.1'}}", does it return "Video"?

Comment: funny enough it does not

Comment: I found this. hope it can help: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/258, 
It seems that we can not do it this way.
Just try other library such as $i18next, may be...